# about heroku postgresql connecct failed

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

When I execute the code on the laptop, it can connect to postgresql.

```
DATABASE_URL = os.popen(config.get('postgresql', 'cmd')).read()[:-1]
db = psycopg2.connect(DATABASE_URL, sslmode='require')
```

Then modified the code as follows, and deploy the code to heroku.

```
DATABASE_URL = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']
db = psycopg2.connect(DATABASE_URL, sslmode='require')
```

It show me this log

2022-05-02T17:08:38.636573+00:00 app[web.1]: psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory

Comment: Does the value of your `DATABASE_URL` appear to point to a real database? Have you provisioned the Heroku Postgres addon, either explicitly or automatically?

Comment: `DATABASE_URL` is point to Heroku Postgres which is addon my heroku app

Comment: You're _entirely sure?_ After the first line in the snippet above, `DATABASE_URL = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']`, your `DATABASE_URL` variable contains something like `postgres://user:password@host:port/database`, and the `host` is somewhere on AWS?

Comment: If so, please [edit] your question and show the full traceback. Please also search your code for other places where you may try to create a database connection.

Comment: omg I found what wrong is it. I change the position `DATABASE_URL = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']`  Then it working!!  Thank you a lot.